# Regshot 1.9.0 works slowly and hangs on Windows 10 version 1803. How to solve?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I use tool [Regshot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/) for finding registry tweaks. This program worked well done on Windows 7, 8.1, 10 LTSB (1607). But, when I decide to work with last Windows 10 version 1803 - taked problems. At the 1st shot, the processing of keys and values takes approximately 5 minutes. The 2nd shot can takes even more time. For example, on Windows 7 the 1st or 2nd shot will take few seconds. On Windows 10 LTSB the 1st or 2nd shot will take aproximately 30 seconds.

Who use this tool and how you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Who use this tool and how you solve this problem?

Configure the regshot.ini-file, [SkipDir]-section: **C:\Windows\servicing\LCU**

```
[Setup]
Flag=3
ExtDir=C:\
Language=English
OutDir=C:\temp
UseLongRegHead=0

[SkipRegKey]
0=

[SkipDir]
0=C:\Windows\servicing\LCU
```